# consulta sacar solo columnas con bit en 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de roles que tiene por columnas `id`, `nombre` de perfil, y `3` columnas mas que estan como `proyecto_1`, `proyecto_2` y `proyecto_3`

```
Id_Perfil   Rol_Nombre      proyecto_1  proyecto_2  proyecto_3  
1           Administrador       1         NULL          1
2           Operativo          NULL         1          NULL
3           Cliente             1           1          NULL
```

Por ejemplo el rol de administrador por asi decirlo, tiene acceso solo a el proyecto `1` y `3`,
el rol Operativo solamente al `2` y el de cliente al `1` y `2`.

Como puedo hacer una consulta de dependiendo el rol me traega solamente los proyectos a los que tiene
acceso,tendria que validar cada columna? como puedo resolver esta consulta y que quede asi:

```
Rol_Nombre      Proyecto_1  proyecto_3  
Administrador       1           1
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Roles where Rol_Nombre = 'Administrador'....
```

Answer (score 0):

Más allá de la consulta sql creo que tienes un problema de diseño. ¿es algo que heredaste o es algo que podes cambiar?

Lo lógico sería que tengas esa información separada en 3 tablas:

- Roles: rolid, rolnombre
- Proyectos: proyId, proyNombre
- RolesProyecto: proyId, rolid

y una tabla que indique a que proyectos tiene acceso cada rol.

Luego para saber a que proyectos tiene acceso cada rol podrías hacer algo asi:

```
select * from proyectoRoles where rolid = 1
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.